# date_i18n function shows today's date instead of provided date

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm triying to display the a span of dates from starting date to ending date in Wordpress in a custom snippet to list events on our website. There are two custom fields relevant for this problem:

- event_date: shows the starting date of the event (using date picker)
- event_date_end: shows the ending date of the event (using date picker, only used when the event is more than one day)

I'm using the code below, It looks right to me but for some reason the second date is set to today's date instead of the date in the event_date_end field. If I display only event_date_end (echo get_field('event_date_end') for instance) the right date shows up but when trying to change how it is displayed for some reason the date changes. Any idea what may cause this? The whole thing is part of a longer snippet so perhaps the error is outside of this scope but I have a feeling I'm not using i18n correctly.

```
$eventduration = date_i18n("d", strtotime(get_field('event_date')))."
".date_i18n("M", strtotime(get_field('event_date')))." -
".date_i18n("d", strtotime(get_field('event_date_end')))."
".date_i18n("M", strtotime(get_field('event_date_end')))."; 
echo $eventduration;

#Should display something like "25 Aug - 28 Aug" but instead shows "25 Aug - 18 Aug"
```

Comment: and what format do you get the date picker dates back in?

Comment: Can you show us what `get_field('event_date')` and `get_field('event_date_end')` return?

Comment: You do realise you could do `date_i18n("d M", strtotime(get_field('event_date')))` and get the day and month all in one go right?

Comment: Not sure if it's better if I provided the whole code snippet, but I belive this is what you asked for:
$d = date("Y-m-d");
 $new_query = new WP_Query (  array (
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'tax_query' => array(
     array(
    'taxonomy' => 'events',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array('featured_event')
     )),          
 'meta_query'=> array(
  array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => $d,
    'type' => 'date',
    'compare' => '>='
  )),
 'meta_key' => 'event_date',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'posts_per_page' => 4
 ) );

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly, I didn't know that.

Comment: FluffyKitten:
get_field('event_date') returns "20200825"
get_field('event_date_end') returns "27/08/2020"

So yeah - there may be a problem here. I have formatted them differently. Gotta look into it.

Comment: Simon, please always post additional info into the quesiton, specially if its code, noone can read code in a comment

Comment: Sorry - I will think of this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a date with `/` as a seperator `strtotime()` it will assume the American date format.

Your date from the date picker is in a logical format. So you will have to change the `/` to a `-` and then `strtotime()` will work correctly for this format

```
$ede = str_replace('/', '-', get_field('event_date_end'));

$eventduration = date_i18n("d M", strtotime(get_field('event_date')))
                 ." - ".
                 date_i18n("d M", strtotime($ede)); 
echo $eventduration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick resonse. I have found the answer now thanks to the questions you asked. event_date_end saved the dates in a different order than the other field. Not sure why that matters but perhaps the way it was saved was not compatible with the function I was using.

get_field('event_date') returns "20200825"
get_field('event_date_end') returns "27/08/2020"

I could change this in the Custom Fields plugin that I'm using to create these fields and now it works.